# Icon doesn't display in iPhone 6+ simulator

Tags: cordova, icons, iphone-6-plus

My icon doesn't display on the iPhone 6+ iOS simulator.

I did all 3x versions for the icon in my xml, and res folder:

```xml
<!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" height="120" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon@3x.png" width="171" height="171" />
```

But I see the PhoneGap one.

How do I get the correct one to display on a iPhone 6+?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. You might try to rebuild your project with `cordova build ios`, and double check the path to your assets. Make sure you have only one config.xml (both your project root and `www/` directory are valid locations

Comment: thank you kindasimple, indeed the 4 new 3x.png weren't in the build... Xcode6 is very unstable for me.

Comment: for what its worth, its working on my machine

Comment: try updating to cordova-iOS 3.7 with `cordova platform update ios` (released today). It looks like there may be a fix for your issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7648

Comment: I put manually the icon in the assets, but yes it seems to be corrected in this new update. Thx